# CSS removed when I change something in Chrome dev tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, nuxt.js

I created one simple nuxt project. Every time when I try to change something in chrome dev tools (for example check and uncheck some css), other css styles will be removed.

Does anybody know why this happens?

The problem happens only in chrome and opera. In Firefox it doesn't happen.

[image]

Comment: For example when I change css on child elements, css on parent element will be removed. I didn't setup enything specific. I created nuxt app, and I just started creating components. You can see video on this link: `we.tl/t-WDrtJuraGu`

Comment: Anybody knows??